# Starling Feathers Screen Navigator

Tags: actionscript-3, starling-framework

I am wondering if there is a way to use this.owner.showScreen(screen_id) from within a class that doesn't inherit Screen?

I am building a footer class (similar to header but with custom controls) that I will include in multiple screens but the class needs to extend Starling Sprite. So basically it is an include file/class.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As the getter method this.owner returns a reference to the screen navigator by which the classes that extend Screen are navigated, it's not possible to do so.

Why not simply create a class say, Footer, that extends feathers.controls.Header and have it have its y property as ***stage.height - this.height*** so that it'll be placed at bottom ? Or place the header on every class at bottom

```
// in initialize method of Screen classes
_header.y = stage.height - _header.height;
```

Answer (score 0):

feelingtheblanks is right, but you shouldn't do that on the initialize (The stage size might not be ready on some mobile devices), also I wouldn't use the stage height, you should use the actualHeight of the component.